# Setting a column value in the SELECT Statement based on a value existing in another table

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 2 tables. One table lists all the records of items we track.  The other table contains flags of attributes of the records in the first table.

For example, Table 1 has columns

```
Tab1ID, Name, Address, Phone
```

Table 2 has these columns

```
Tab2ID, Tab1ID, FlagName
```

There is a 1 to Many relationship between Table1 and Table2 linked by Tab1ID.

I'd like to create a query that has all the records from Table1 in it.  However, if one of the records in Table2 has a Flagname=Retired (with a matching Tab1ID) then I want a "Y" to show up in the select column list otherwise an "N".

I think it might look something like this:

```
Select Name, Address, Phone, (select something in table2)
from Table1
where Tab1ID > 1;
```

It's the subquery in the column that has me stumped.

Pat

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
Select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.tab1id = t1.tab1id and t2.flagname = 'Retired'
                         )
             then 'Y' else 'N'
       end) as retired_flag
from Table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a normal join returning multiple records, but convert them to bits with case statements. Then use that as the subquery and pull the max value for each bit column.

```
select
    name
    ,address
    ,phone
    ,max(retired_flag)
from (
    select
        table1.name
        ,table1.address
        ,table1.phone
        ,case when table2.flagname = 'retired' then 1 else 0 end as [retired_flag]
    from table1
    left join table2
        on table1.tab1id = table2.tab1id
    where tab1id > 1
    ) tbl
group by
    name
    ,address
    ,phone
```